# Batch file to count occurrences

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a plain text file like this:

```
...
... TYPE: alm01, ........
...
...
...
... TYPE: almBB, ........
...
...
... TYPE: out, ......
...
... TYPE: in, ......
... TYPE: almBB, ........
... TYPE: out, ......
... TYPE: out, ......
```

(ellipsis is stuff from the line)

so using a batch file or `cmd` command (using pipes if necessary) I would like to count and output the number of occurrences of each type, from the example above, I want to output:

```
alm01 1
almBB 2
out 3
in 1
```

How can I do this?

**FIRST ATTEMPT:** (Not working)

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

rem Configuration
set "file=test.log"

rem Clean environment
for /f "tokens=1 delims==" %%v in ('set _type_ 2^>nul') do set "%%v="

rem Search required lines
for /f "tokens=*" %%l in ('findstr "TYPE:" "%file%"') do (

    rem Now we have the whole line

    set "t=%%l"

    rem Remove the prefix of the line
    set "t=%t:*TYPE: =%"
    set "t=%t:~1%"

    rem Remove the suffix of the line (from comma to end) and 
    rem increment counter of type
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%t in ('echo %t%') do set /a "_type_%%t+=1"
)

rem Enumerate find types and echo type and number of occurrences
rem The inner loop is to allow underscores inside type
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=_" %%a in ('set _type_ 2^>nul') do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%v in ("%%a") do echo %%v %%w
)

rem Clean and exit
endlocal
exit /b
```

Comment: that would be easy in bash. MS-DOS mean the pre-Win32 system, or just command prompt (cmd.exe)?

Comment: Yes, the question from V-X is critical. Do you really mean MS-DOS batch? or are you using Windows batch? MS-DOS capabilities are more limited.

Comment: @dbenham I want to do this with a bat file and execute it from a windows command (cmd) prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Configuration
    set "file=plaintext.txt"

    rem Clean environment
    for /f "tokens=1 delims==" %%v in ('set _type_ 2^>nul') do set "%%v="

    rem Search required lines
    for /f "tokens=*" %%l in ('findstr "TYPE:" "%file%"') do (

        rem Now we have the whole line
        set "t=%%l"

        rem Can't handle it inside the for loop. Go out to do it
        call :handleType
    )

    rem Enumerate find types and echo type and number of occurrences
    rem The inner loop is to allow underscores inside type
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=_" %%a in ('set _type_ 2^>nul') do (
        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%v in ("%%b") do echo %%v %%w
    )

    rem Clean and exit
    endlocal
    exit /b

:handleType
    rem Remove the prefix of the line
    set "t=%t:*TYPE: =%"
    rem Remove spaces (not needed as OP stated and giving problems)
    set "t=%t: =%"

    rem Remove the suffix of the line (from comma to end) and 
    rem increment counter of type
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%t in ("%t:"=%") do set /a "_type_%%~t+=1"

    goto :EOF
```

EDITED

The problem is real file contains some special characters (`!` at least) inside lines, and those characters are expanded because the delayed expansion enabled, generating the error indicated by the OP.

To handle it, delayed expansion needs to be off, but since we are reading the file inside a for loop, to get access to the changed value of the variables delayed expansion needs to be on, so, leave it off and move lines of code for type management to a subroutine outside the for loop.

Comment: I have just tested it and it is not working. It says operator missed. Removing the prefix of the line is not working. Also you have some mistakes in the scripting. See the one I have posted with mistakes corrected. Anyway, it is not working.

Comment: Sorry but it is not working, the same error: "Operator missed". Furthermore, i think you have some syntax mistakes: when Enumerating found types and echo type and number of occurrences, in the inner loop it should be %%a instead of %%b. Also when removing prefix of the line in the handleType, at the beginning of the line after performing the set, it keeps an whitespace that you should remove using for example, set "t=%t:~1%". Finally, last line goto :EOF, where is EOF tag in the script? thanks a lot.

Comment: @user304602: At what line the error happens? %%b is ok, outer for separates `_type_` (in `%%a`) from the rest of the line (in `%%b`) using `tokens=1,*` and inner for separates type (in `%%v`) from the count (in `%%w`). The white space (one whitespace) is included in prefix remove. If there are more spaces, adapt as needed. `:eof` is a "predefined" label availabel when extensions are enabled and means `End Of File`. See `goto /?` for an explanation.

Comment: @user304602: How are your "TYPE" values really? What values can it have?

Comment: Now it is working, sorry. Only one mistake in your script: In the handletype body, in the for loop, instead of ("%t:"=%") is ("%t: =%"). Please, correct it. Also could you explain me why in the inner loop to enumerate found type is %%b and not %%a? I do not understand.

Comment: @user304602 No, the quote is to avoid errors if the right part of the line contains quotes. It should be where it is. I've added a space removal line just before.

Comment: @user304602: All the types are stored in environment variables in the form `_type_typename=count`, and are retrieved using a `set` command  that shows lines in the indicated format. It is necessary to separate the first part of the line (`_type_`), so a `token=1,*` clause is used, two tokens indicated. It will split the line in `type` and `typename=count` tokens (delimiters removed), first token is placed inside the `for` variable (`%%a` in this case), and the next in the next alphabetical variable (`%%b`). Two tokens, two variables.

Comment: Hi, what if the %t has special characters?