# How to count unique string with special characters in window bat file

Tags: batch-file, window

I am referring to this sample to do a unique string count. [Batch file to count occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489550/batch-file-to-count-occurrences)
However, my string may include special characters eg. "orange c=US". If the string has special characters, the count won't work.

input:

```
[SUCCESS] xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,orange c=US,xxxx,xxxx
[SUCCESS] xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,orange c=CA,xxxx,xxxx
[SUCCESS] xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,orange c=US,xxxx,xxxx
[SUCCESS] xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,orange c=US,xxxx,xxxx
[SUCCESS] xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,orange c=CA,xxxx,xxxx
[SUCCESS] xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,apple c=US,xxxx,xxxx
[SUCCESS] xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,apple c=CA,xxxx,xxxx
```

output:

```
orange c=US  3
orange c=CA  2
apple c=US 1
apple c=CA 1
```

code:

```
set "file=test.out.log"
(
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7 delims=," %%a in ('findstr /I /N /C:"[SUCCESS]" "%file%"') do (
    set "t=%%d" <--- %%d will extract "orange c=US"
    call :handleType
)

rem Enumerate find types and echo type and number of occurrences
rem The inner loop is to allow underscores inside type
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=_" %%a in ('set _type_ 2^>nul') do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%v in ("%%b") do (
      echo %%v %%w
    )
)) > output.txt

rem Clean and exit
endlocal
exit /b
pause > nul
:handleType
  rem %t% ----> orange c=US
  set "t=%t:'=%"

for /f "tokens=*" %%t in ("%t:"=%") do (
    set /a "_type_%%~t+=1"
)
goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

Just replace the special character `=` (and the space) by another one for the count, and replace back such characters for the output:

**EDIT**: *Code modified as requested in a posterior comment*

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Count items
for /F "tokens=4 delims=," %%d in ('findstr /I /L "[SUCCESS]" test.txt') do (
   set "item=%%d"

   rem Replace special characters
   for %%a in ("+=PLUS" "/=SLASH") do (
      for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%b in (%%a) do set "item=!item:%%b=%%c!"
   )

   rem Separate on SPace and equal-sign characters
   for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims== " %%x in ("!item!") do (
      set /A "count[%%x_%%y_%%z]+=1"
   )
)

REM set count[

rem Show counts
for /F "tokens=2-5 delims=[_]=" %%a in ('set count[') do (

   rem Replace back special characters
   set "item=%%a"
   for %%a in ("PLUS=+" "SLASH=/") do (
      for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%b in (%%a) do set "item=!item:%%b=%%c!"
   )

   echo !item! %%b=%%c  %%d
)
```

Input:

```
[SUCCESS] xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,orange c=US,xxxx,xxxx
[SUCCESS] xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,orange c=CA,xxxx,xxxx
[SUCCESS] xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,orange c=US,xxxx,xxxx
[SUCCESS] xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,orange c=US,xxxx,xxxx
[SUCCESS] xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,orange c=CA,xxxx,xxxx
[SUCCESS] xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,apple c=US,xxxx,xxxx
[SUCCESS] xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,apple c=CA,xxxx,xxxx
[SUCCESS] xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,Grape+ c=US,xxxx,xxxx
[SUCCESS] xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,Grape+ c=CA,xxxx,xxxx
[SUCCESS] xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,Grape/L c=US,xxxx,xxxx
[SUCCESS] xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,Grape/L c=CA,xxxx,xxxx
```

Output:

```
apple c=CA  1
apple c=US  1
Grape+ c=CA  1
Grape+ c=US  1
Grape/L c=CA  1
Grape/L c=US  1
orange c=CA  2
orange c=US  3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I just realised some string maybe have other special character eg. Grape+ c=US, Grape/L c=CA. Something like this.

Comment: See the edit in my answer. This would be easier is you show us the _real_ data since the very beginning... **`:(`**

Comment: @Aacini, whilst your code may work with the example file submitted by the OP, and your own above, I doubt it is really what would be used in a real world scenario. I say that because, my assumption is that the input file will not only contain lines which the OP wishes to capture, _(otherwise the string `SUCCESS` would be irrelevant wouldn't it?)_. Regardless of that, your particular capture line `findstr /I "[SUCCESS]" test.txt`, will return every line which contains any instance of any one of these characters: `C`, `E`, `S`, and `U`, which I'd wager is not really what you intended to capture.

Comment: @Compo: Yes. I missing the `/L` switch in `findstr` command. I just added it to my code. Thanks for noted it! **`:)`**

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative method available from Windows 10 onwards, which may assist you, *(subject to whatever secret 'special characters' exist within the target field of your CSV input file)*:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "ifile=inputfile.csv"
Set "tfile=%TEMP%\$.log"
For /F "Tokens=4 Delims=," %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R
 /C:"^\[SUCCESS\][^,][^,]*,[^,][^,]*,[^,][^,]*,[^,][^,]*" "%ifile%" 2^>NUL'
) Do (Echo %%G) 1>>"%tfile%"
If Not Exist "%tfile%" GoTo :EOF
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\sort.exe /Unique "%tfile%"
 ') Do (SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & Set "}=0"
    For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%H In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /X
     /C:"%%G" "%tfile%"') Do Set /A } += 1
    Echo %%G,!}!& EndLocal)
Del "%tfile%"
Pause
```

Expected output, *(I used a comma delimiter here, as those should not exist in the field string)*:

```
apple c=CA,1
apple c=US,1
orange c=CA,2
orange c=US,3
```

**[EDIT /]**

It should have no difficulties with your additional example strings `Grape+ c=US`, and `Grape/L c=CA` from your [comment to another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69569510/how-to-count-unique-string-with-special-characters-in-window-bat-file#comment122971992_69571224).

Comment: I wonder what is the specific Windows 10 version feature in your code that don't allow to use it in previous versions...

Comment: I was told that the undocumented `/Unique` option with `sort.exe` was new to Windows 10 @Aacini. _(I do not own a Windows PC, so I have never tried to see if that information is correct, or even if it is limited to specific editions)_.

Comment: Uh, ok! I didn't realized that...

Comment: Your solution executes `findstr` command for _each_ different string in the file! If the file is large, and the unique strings are numerous, this method would take too much time...

Comment: Technically @Aacini, it executes `FindStr` once for the entire input file. Then it executes `FindStr` against each unique string returned from the target field. So I suppose, it may take a little time if there are a large number of unique field strings to count, but FindStr is  a very quick and efficient utility in my experience. By all means, feel free to run some speed tests. I would also say that is better than trying to replace every possible 'special character' with a string, _(which may match a literal string in the target field)_, and to code that for every possible 'special character'.